# when using MPI_Isend() MPI_and Irecv(), should the pair use the same request? in case the message is already an array, how it should be passed?

Tags: mpi

In this code I am trying to broadcast using non blocking send and receive as a practice. I have multiple questions and issues.
1.Should I pair Isend() and Irecv() to use the same request?
2.When the message is an array, how should it be passed? in this case, message or &message?
3.Why I cannot run this code on less or more than 8 processors? if the rank doesn't exit, shouldn't it just go on without executing that piece of code?
4.The snippet on the at the bottom is there in order to print the total time once, but the waitall() does not work, and I do not understand why.
5. When passing arrays longer than 2^12, I get segmentation error, while I have checked the limits of Isend() and Irecv() and they supposed to handle even bigger length messages.
6.I used long double for record the time, is this a common or good practice? when I used smaller variables like float or double I would get nan.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<math.h>
#include<mpi.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

  MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
  int i, rank, size, ready;
  long int N = pow(2, 10);
  float* message = (float *)malloc(sizeof(float *) * N + 1);
  long double start, end;

  MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);
  MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &size);
  //MPI_Request* request = (MPI_Request *)malloc(sizeof(MPI_Request *) * size);
  MPI_Request request[size-1];
/*Stage I: -np 8*/
  if(rank == 0){
    for(i = 0; i < N; i++){
      message[i] = N*rand();
      message[i] /= rand();
      }
    start = MPI_Wtime();
    MPI_Isend(&message, N, MPI_FLOAT, 1, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &request[0]);
    MPI_Isend(&message, N, MPI_FLOAT, 2, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &request[1]);
    MPI_Isend(&message, N, MPI_FLOAT, 4, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &request[3]);
    printf("Processor root-rank %d- sent the message...\n", rank);
  }
  if (rank == 1){
    MPI_Irecv(&message, N, MPI_FLOAT, 0, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &request[0]);
    MPI_Wait(&request[0], MPI_STATUS_IGNORE);
    printf("Processor rank 1 received the message.\n");
    MPI_Isend(&message, N, MPI_FLOAT, 3, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &request[2]);
    MPI_Isend(&message, N, MPI_FLOAT, 5, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &request[4]);

  }
  if(rank == 2){
    MPI_Irecv(&message, N, MPI_FLOAT, 0, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &request[1]);
    MPI_Wait(&request[1], MPI_STATUS_IGNORE);
    printf("Processor rank 2 received the message.\n");
    MPI_Isend(&message, N, MPI_FLOAT, 6, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &request[5]);
  }
  if(rank == 3){
    MPI_Irecv(&message, N, MPI_FLOAT, 1, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &request[2]);
    MPI_Wait(&request[2], MPI_STATUS_IGNORE);
    printf("Processor rank 3 received the message.\n");
    MPI_Isend(&message, N, MPI_FLOAT, 7, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &request[6]);
  }
  if(rank == 4){
    MPI_Irecv(&message, N, MPI_FLOAT, 0, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &request[3]);
    MPI_Wait(&request[3], MPI_STATUS_IGNORE);
    printf("Processor rank 4 received the message.\n");
  }
  if(rank == 5){
    MPI_Irecv(&message, N, MPI_FLOAT, 1, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &request[4]);
    MPI_Wait(&request[4], MPI_STATUS_IGNORE);
    printf("Processor rank 5 received the message.\n");
  }
  if(rank == 6){
    MPI_Irecv(&message, N, MPI_FLOAT, 2, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &request[5]);
    MPI_Wait(&request[5], MPI_STATUS_IGNORE);
    printf("Processor rank 6 received the message.\n");
  }
  if(rank == 7){
    MPI_Irecv(&message, N, MPI_FLOAT, 3, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &request[6]);
    MPI_Wait(&request[6], MPI_STATUS_IGNORE);
    printf("Processor rank 7 received the message.\n");
  }
  /*MPI_Testall(size-1,request,&ready, MPI_STATUS_IGNORE);*/
/*  if (ready){*/
    end = MPI_Wtime();
    printf("Total Time: %Lf\n", end - start);
/*}*/

  MPI_Finalize();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Each MPI task runs in its own address space, so there is no correlation between `request[1]` on rank `0` and `request[1]` on rank `2`. That means you do **not have to** "pair" the requests. That being said, if you think "pairing" the requests improves the readability of your code, you might want to do so even if this is not required.
2. the buffer parameter of `MPI_Isend()` and `MPI_Irecv()` is a pointer to the start of the data, this is `message` (and **not** `&message`) here.
3. if you run with let's say 2 MPI tasks, `MPI_Send(..., dest=2, ...)` on rank `0` will fail because there `2` is an invalid rank in the `MPI_COMM_WORLD` communicator.
4. many requests are uninitialized when `MPI_Waitall()` (well, `MPI_Testall()` here) is invoked. One option is to first initialize all of them to `MPI_REQUEST_NULL`.
5. using `&message` results in memory corruption and that likely explains the crash.
6. From the MPI standard, the prototype is `double MPI_Wtime()`, so you'd rather use `double` here (the NaN likely come from the memory corruption described above)

Comment: I am confused about the request. So request in Isend() and Irecv() is just a handle that can be used through wait() and test() to verify the status of send/receive? and when does initialization come into play?

Comment: When Testall() or Waitall() is used, it will only return when all tasks are completed, then the next instruction will be executed for all of the processors(ranks), kind of synchronization?

Comment: This version of code, runs until 2^12 array size, I have the version without direct addressing of messages- without &-and that one also have segmentation faults.

Comment: `MPI_Isend(..., &req)` does initialize `req` (same for `MPI_Irecv()`. For example, on rank `0`, `request[2]` is not initialized when `MPI_Testall()` is invoked. `MPI_Waitall()` is a local operation in a sense that it returns when the (local) requests complete. For example, `MPI_Waitall(()` completing on rank `0` means all the send requests have completed (e.g. the send buffers can be reused). It says nothing about the messages being received on the other ranks. Note `MPI_STATUSES_IGNORE` must be used (instead of `MPI_STATUS_IGNORE`) with `MPI_Waitall()` and `MPI_Testall()`.

Comment: Also, allocate `sizeof(float) * ...` instead `sizeof(float *) * ...`

Comment: I did the changes for message array, malloc and double datatype for time, and I got yet another weird result. I mean the time duration doesn't make sense.

Processor rank 6 received the message.
Total Time: 1606415660.558836

Comment: Worked! I truly appreciate this!

Comment: How can I only print the max total time?

Comment: Use `MPI_Reduce(..., MPI_MAX, ...)` to retrieve the max time.

Comment: And initialize `start` on all ranks!

Comment: I implemented according to your advice, when running the terminal doesn't return, so I posted the code in a new question. I appreciate this very much!